# How to list each process from ps aux, if they repeat, keep a running count and format

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ps

Right now, I use this:

```
ps aux | grep (Example_Process_1) -c
```

This returns:

```
221
```

This is nice, it gives me a count, but I have to do it for each of the 100 different items we have:

For instance,

```
ps aux | grep (Example_Process_1) -c
ps aux | grep (Example_Process_2) -c
ps aux | grep (Example_Process_3) -c
```

And so forth.
What I want is a command to run ONCE, but the output is something similar:

```
Example Process 1 - 221
Example Process 2 - 360
Example Process 3 - 500
```

I realize I can write a script that will execute each of these, then I can output them to the screen, but it is large and clunky.  Does anyone know any short clean code to accomplish this?

Comment: how about an array storing all process names and a for loop?

Comment: Use sed to get the imformation you want, pipe it through sort and then through uniq -c and then maybe sort -n. Or use awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps -e -o cmd | cut -f 1 -d ' '  | sort | uniq -c
```

For all process, print the command line. Get the first word of the command line. Sort the list. Count occurrences of each.

Comment: This gets me where I want, thank you.  Is there any way to make it sort by the highest counts first?  If not its cool I'm satisfied.  Thank you